# Почему не работает .replace()?

Tags: javascript

```
const str = "1030"
const test = str.replace('/.0$/', '')

console.log(test)
//"1030"
```

В ответе я бы хотел получить "10". Почему replace() работает не корректно?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Паттерн не надо заключать в кавычки. Надо просто так:

```
str.replace(/.0$/, '')
```